# Mongoid deleting embedded documents does not persist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have been running into an issue for hours and have Googled myself senseless.

I have a Mongoid model with an embedded document, like so:

```
embeds_many :tags, :as => :taggable
```

For some reason, attempting to delete this document appears to work in the console but then the documents come back after a reload. I have tried the following:

```
model.tags.delete_all

model.tags.each do |tag|
  tag.delete
end

model.tags.destroy_all
```

After all of the above, I can confirm that model.tags returns an empty array. Then to be safe, I even call model.save. If I reload the model, all of the embedded tags come back.

What is the correct way to delete embedded documents using Mongoid?

Comment: which version or Mongoid you use ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well Its very simple but tricky ...

When you delete the tags , You need to reload the parent object.

**Code**

```
model.tags.delete_all
model.reload

 model.tags.each do |tag|
  tag.delete
 end
 model.reload

model.tags.destroy_all
model.reload
```

This is the way your model will be reloaded and you will get right object

Comment: Hey, is there a way to delete multiple embedded tasks in one go without reloading ? like a partial destroy_all ?

Comment: I did not get your comments . Can you give bit more explanation

Comment: Yeah sorry, I actually created a separate SO for that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45615471/mongoid-delete-a-subset-of-invalid-embedded-documents-in-one-go